# timeout probability

Tags: probability

I'm trying to calculate an appropriate timeout time for a real time simulator that I'm writing:

For p = probability of success, the time for a successful request = m, and the time for a failed attempt = f. What is the average time for 5 successful requests?

Comment: This might be better suited for the Mathematics portion of Stack Exchange since it doesn't directly relate to programming.

Comment: Note that average times might not be the best metric for timeouts, I would be more interested in quantiles (for instance, time sufficient for 90% of succesful request to complete).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's call the total number of tries x.

```
x = 5p + (x-5)(1-p)
x = 5 / p
```

The total time would be

```
t = 5m + (x-5)f
```

or

```
t = 5m + (5 / p - 5)f
```

If m=1, f=2, and p=0.1, the answer should be 5 * 1 + 45 * 2 = 95. This checks out.

There might be errors in here, but I did my best.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably more appropriate on the stats exchange, by the way, but here's the answer:

If you want the average time, you need to average over the possible total number of trials required to get your five successes. This could be anywhere from 5 to infinite (it requires at least 5 trials to get 5 successes, and you could in theory have an infinitely long sequence of failures). I would suggest you could happily cut this off at a reasonable point to get an answer accurate to several decimal places for anything other than pathological values of p. Let n be the number of trials, from which we want to observe x=5 successes. The probability for 5 successes in n trials is given by the [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), parameterised by x, n, and p. Let `Bin(x; n,p)` be the binomial probability, then the time associated with this is:

```
5m + (n-5)f
```

To get the expectation (average) of this quantity, then you want the sum:

```
Bin(5; n,p) * 5m + (n-5)f
```

for for n=5 to n=inf. Depending on your value of p, you should be able to stop at n=20 to 30 and still obtain fairly accurate answers. Beware if you're using a naive implementation of the binomial probability that the computation of the binomial coefficient, which involves a term of n!, may fail for moderately large n, so you may want to consider the normal approximation to the binomial.